# Different accounts for Google login

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, google-signin

I'm developing an Android application using Ionic. Since I'm using the Google login for the authentication, I had to enable the OAuth and generate the Api keys through a first account used for internal tests. Now, I would like to publish the app on the play store using my company's account. Can I do it without migrating the API from the first account to the company one? These would be the steps I would perform:

1. Publish the app using the company's account.
2. From the Play Store console, copy the SHA1 of the app
3. On my first account, enable the google login on that SHA1

Would it work?